# Homework assignment using Java/Swing

Tags: java, swing

I've got an assignment in a class about user interfaces and usability testing. I have to do something that I'm sure I can figure out how to do programatically, but I have no experience with swing so I have no idea what components to use to do the job. My background is in C# so I'm fumbling at times trying to find the right component to use in NetBeans.

Based on the description below, can anybody recommend what kind of text field will do the job? I was thinking jFormattedTextField (based on the name) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

---

Submit a Java program that will run on the Linux installation in the general lab (EN-2036). 
Provide the following functionality:

- load the output of the last  command (from a file) into a text viewing area that 
  allows the user to browse the data
- bold all login names only (not the whole line)
- bold all occurrences of a user-specified login name
- bold all occurrences of a user-specified set of login names

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJTextArea.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework

I thought it best to clean up the tag as you have told us it is an assignment for your class in your question body :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JEditorPane or JTextpane, these allow you to add style to text inside them

[Tutorial Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)